# How do I install the datepicker widget in ipywidgets?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

It seems like I don't have the `DatePicker` widget which is pretty odd. I tried installing / unistalling `ipywidgets` but no luck.

Any idea how to install it?

```
import ipywidgets as ipyw
ipyw.DatePicker
# AttributeError: module 'ipywidgets' has no attribute 'DatePicker'
ipyw.__version__
# 5.2.2
```

running python3.5

Comment: you hv a spelling mistake >> ipywidgwts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up needing to upgrade `ipywidgets` but to a specific package.

ie this didn't work:

```
pip install ipywidgets -U
```

but this worked:

```
pip install ipywidgets==6.0.0b6
```

Comment: Isn't there something like %latest?